# How to split a parent class that implements an abstract class in Dart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, partial-classes

I want to use some partial classes in Flutter but somehow it does not work with an implemented abstract class. I give an example

**my_interface.dart**

```
abstract class MyInterface {
  void method1();
  void method2();
}
```

**my_parent.dart**

```
import 'package:XYZ/core/init/network/firebase/my_interface.dart';

part 'my_child.dart';
class MyParent implements MyInterface {

  MyParent();

  @override
  void method1() {}
}
```

**my_child.dart**

```
part of 'my_parent.dart';
class MyChild extends MyParent {

_MyChild() : super();

  @override
  void method2() {}
}
```

as you can see, my abstract class has 2 methods and I want to write the body of method1 in my parent class and the body of method2 in my child class.

then when I call these methods, I should be able to call as follow

```
MyParent().method1();
MyParent().method2();
```

is it possible to do that in dart?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this:

```
MyParent().method1();
MyParent().method2();
```

It looks like you specifically want to use an instance of `MyParent` to call a method you only `@override` in subclass `MyChild`. This won't work for a very good reason. You might have multiple classes that inherit from `MyParent`, e.g. `MyChild2` and `MyChild3`, so if you could retroactively rewrite `MyParent` from within `MyChild` then it wouldn't only change `MyChild` and `MyParent`, but also `MyChild2` and `MyChild3`. This would cause major issues for everyone. The point of `@override` so is that you can change a method in a subclass **without** changing it in the superclass. Also, `MyParent` has to already be defined in order for `MyChild` to inherit from it, so wouldn't you get a paradox if `MyParent` relied on `MyChild` for it's `method2` implementation?

If you want to use `MyParent` to call a function that you don't know at runtime, then just give `MyParent` a callback field and provide it when ready. Alternatively, you could create a `mixin` that implements `method2` and use `class MyParent extends MyInterface with MyMixin`.

Also, if you don't provide a concrete implementation for a method in your `abstract` class then you must do so in every subclass. This means that you need to `@override` `method2` in `MyParent` anyway, or else define it in `MyInterface`. [See here](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#non_abstract_class_inherits_abstract_member)

Answer (score 0):

> I should be able to call as follow
>
> ```dart
> MyParent().method1();
> MyParent().method2();
> ```

There are two problems:

- `MyParent` is not a valid class.  Since it's not `abstract`, it must be construcible, and therefore *all* of its inherited methods must have implementations from somewhere.
- `MyParent().method2()` does not make sense.  `MyParent` implements only `method1`.  What do you expect `MyParent().method2()` to do?  Where should its implementation come from?

If you want `MyParent` to only partially implement `MyInterface`, you can:

1. Make `MyParent` also `abstract`.
2. Either:

   - Require that callers construct `MyChild` instead of `MyParent`.
   - Give `MyParent` a `factory` constructor (or `static` method) that constructs and returns a `MyChild` instance.